# Superpowered API - SuperpoweredDecoder::decode does not return 0 for end of file

Tags: android, c++, audio, android-ndk

I am using the Superpowered audio API in a Android project.

I want to load a small wav file (10 ms length) using the `SuperpoweredDecoder` class. If I understood correctly I should call the `decode` method in a loop until it returns 0 for end of file.

My small file is already read completely in the first round but `decode` returns 1 (SUPERPOWEREDDECODER_OK) again and again. If I call `decode` once without the `while` audio data is read in as wanted but this only works for very short audio samples.

```
SuperpoweredDecoder *decoder = new SuperpoweredDecoder();
decoder->open(click1Path, false, click1Offset, click1Length, 0);

while(decoder->decode(intBuffer, &samplesDecoded) == SUPERPOWEREDDECODER_OK) {
    //do something with intBuffer
}
```

http://superpowered.com/docs/class_superpowered_decoder.html

Comment: As a workaround I use the number of decoded samples as break condition at the end of the loop: `if(samplesDecoded == 0) break;` I do not think that this is the way it is meant to be used but at least it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WAV files are read in longer chunks than 10 ms in Superpowered, because it's tuned for maximum decoding/read performance.

Although a smaller file will not cause any bad memory access, the decoder may be confused that the first read is immediately an eof too.

Check for samplesDecoded < 1, so your code will look something like:

```
while ((decoder->decode(intBuffer, &samplesDecoded) == SUPERPOWEREDDECODER_OK) && (samplesDecoded > 0)) {
    //do something with intBuffer
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gabor. Yes, checking for samplesDecoded works as I already mentioned in my comment. But I think this should be considered as a bug. Software should not get confused.